# Implement a N-aryTreeLSTM version of the TreeLSTM in TensorFlow Fold

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, fold

I'm trying to implement this paper [TreeLSTM](http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.00075) by using [TensorFlow Fold](https://github.com/tensorflow/fold). Actually, in Tensorflow Fold, there's already an example of TreeLSTM but in a BinaryTreeLSTM version, here's the tutorial: https://github.com/tensorflow/fold/blob/master/tensorflow_fold/g3doc/sentiment.ipynb

What I'm trying to do now is to implement a real NaryTreeLSTM, means that a LSTM node can be the parent of any number of children, not just 2 like in the above tutorial.

This is my attempt at trying to fold the tree, this is a modify version of `logits_and_state()` in the above example "

```
 def logits_and_state():
  """Creates a block that goes from tokens to (logits, state) tuples."""
  word2vec = (td.GetItem(0) >> td.InputTransform(lookup_word) >>
              td.Scalar('int32') >> word_embedding)

  children_num = 
  children2vec_list = list()
  children2vec_list.append(embed_subtree())
  for i in range(children_num):
    children2vec_list.append(embed_subtree())

  children2vec = tuple(children2vec_list)

  # Trees are binary, so the tree layer takes two states as its input_state.

  zero_state = td.Zeros((tree_lstm.state_size,) * 2)
  # Input is a word vector.
  zero_inp = td.Zeros(word_embedding.output_type.shape[0])

  # word_case = 
  word_case = td.AllOf(word2vec, zero_state)
  children_case = td.AllOf(zero_inp, children2vec)

  tree2vec = td.OneOf(lambda x: 1 if len(x) == 1 else 2), [(1,word_case),(2,children_case)])
  return tree2vec >> tree_lstm >> (output_layer, td.Identity())
```

The `children_num` is the thing that I'm struggling at this moment, I have no idea to get out that number, eventhought I know that the length of children can be obtained by `td.GetItem(1)` ==> will produce a block that contains an array of children ==> how to get out the real number of that block?

You may say that I should try PyTorch or some others DL framework that also provides Dynamic Computation Graph, but in my case, the requirement is strict with Tensorflow Fold.

Comment: Just curious, did you find answer you're looking for?